# angular-calendar - month date, event date mismatch

Tags: angular, time, angular-calendar

I am using angular-calendar version - 0.26.4.

When event with date 2023-02-03T00:00:00.000Z added to the events array it get shifted to
Feb 2nd. Following is the object receives in the calendar template. I checked a place to configure time zone but couldn't find such.

```
{
  "date": "2023-02-02T18:30:00.000Z",
  "isPast": false,
  "isToday": false,
  "isFuture": true,
  "isWeekend": false,
  "inMonth": true,
  "events": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "start": "2023-02-03T00:00:00.000Z",
      "title": "4",
      "color": {
        "primary": "#e3bc08",
        "secondary": "#FDF1BA"
      }
    }
  ],
  "badgeTotal": 1
}
```

Following is the way comparing dates

[image]

Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is because `Date` object by default has time zone applied to them. If you would do `new Date().getUtc...`, you would see that these are actually returning different results from your current date.

To counter-act this, you can use `Date.UTC()` constructor (more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC)). This creates date with +0 GMT time zone. If you pass this to angular calendar it will then properly show it.